# why can't I squat with my feet flat?

Tags: pain

I don't know why I can't squat. I'm young (9) Hopefully There's not something with me. I hope I can help myself. And fix what's wrong with me.

Comment: Stack Exchange terms of service require that you be at least 13 years of age to participate on the site: [Why can't I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old, or if I'm under 16 years old and from the EU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the querent is underage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for administrative action.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with you. Many people (especially Americans) stop being able to squat as toddlers because we sit in chairs and wear raised heeled shoes, which reduces flexibility in our hips and ankles. You can learn to squat again mostly by just practicing. Especially at a young age, you will likely find quick success.

You will progress faster if you are able to stay in the squat position for a couple minutes; you might have to work up to it. It's OK to hold onto something, or lean against something while you practice.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of improving your range of motion, great to start young.

I do not think there is anything wrong with you, it is more a question of your body not being used to the squat position.

If you place an small stable object (maybe a book) under the heels of your feet You can start training the squat position. After a while it will get easier. If you want you can also try to tighten your shin muscles in order to pull you forward into the squat. That will help your calf muscles relax.